# Filter elements of fetched collection. EclipseLInk. Criteria API

Tags: eclipselink, criteria-api

I have an object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "adm", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "loginUser"))
public class User implements GenericEntityPK<Integer> {

    private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<Permission>(0);
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_l_permission", catalog = "adm", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "idUser", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "idPermission", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<Permission> getPermissions() {
        return this.permissions;
    }
}
```

I want to select user entity and fetch collection of permissions, with where clause. In other words permissions collection must contain only elements that satisfy where conditions.
I've tried to do it with **SetJoin** but with no success..

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you instead query for the permissions that match the user and filter you want when needed.  You can even cache this collection in your entity with a transient collection to pass it around in the object.  Using filters on relationships ends up causing problems and corrupts the cache as what is in the object is no longer a true representation of what is in the database.

That said, there is no JPA way to do it, but Eclipselink supports [additional criteria](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_additionalcriteria.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already done as said - query for permissions and filter them with a separate query.